# How to see mails sent using a website's contact form in an email client?

Tags: email, gmail, email-client

In the "Contact Us" section of some websites, you enter your name, email address, message and send. Although these emails are sent from your email address, they do not show up at an email client such as Gmail's client.

My question is, how am I supposed to configure Gmail client to show emails sent in such manner?

Comment: You are just entering your address, not using Gmail's services.

Comment: @SalvoF But the mail is sent from the same email address that I use in say, Gmail. Is there no way to see those types of mails I sent?

Comment: If you need to write your address, then **you are not** sending an email with your say, Gmail resources. It's just that website's form collecting and forwarding data.

Comment: @SalvoF A detailed answer explaining the nuts and bolts, comparing what goes on behind the two methods would be great. Because I really don't know these stuff.

Comment: What happens behind the scenes may vary. Usually, server on which site runs, takes data from that webpage and sends an email to site owner's email, by using server's smtp service or any other. It's all their resources, server side.

Other sites just use a "mailto:" link; in this case you'd be sending a "real" email. This particular system is disappearing, as it exposes recipient's address, with consequent spamminng issues.

Comment: @SalvoF So, my sent email is stored on their servers. Hence, to be able to access it, I somehow need to be able to access their servers. Is that right?

Comment: I do not encourage anybody to hack servers ;-) Some sites (few, actually) send you an immediate automatic reply as a courtesy, containing your request.

Comment: @SalvoF I see. So in this case, I am not _supposed to_ access my sent email.

Comment: `Although these emails are sent from your email address, ` - Like where does this happen ? It is very easy to spoof emails but, it should in no way send FROM my own account, it should only send TO!

Comment: @Utku, it's your message, **not** your **email**